# Command Prompt (Win8) using bash?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, bash

Is there any way to use (basic) bash commands on Command Prompt from Windows 8? I will still use more sophisticated commands in my scripts, but for simple navigation, etc. is it possible to setup Command Prompt to use things like `ls`, `pwd`, and `cd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use Powershell. It's built-in since Windows Vista and the successor of the good old cmd.exe.

This command (called Cmdlet in PS)

> Get-Alias

will show you which aliases exist for Powershell commands. The typical bash commands are among them.

```
PS C:\Users\User> pwd

Path
----
C:\Users\User


PS C:\Users\User> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\User


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----        18.08.2013     10:56            .android
d----        14.06.2013     19:23            .config
d----        11.08.2013     16:57            .freemind
d----        01.04.2013     21:13            .splunk
d----        12.12.2012     08:36            .ssh
d----        17.10.2012     07:22            Cisco Packet Tracer 5.3.3
d----        16.04.2013     18:25            Citrix
d-r--        13.10.2013     23:48            Contacts
d-r--        04.01.2014     14:28            Desktop
d----        25.05.2013     00:35            deviantART
d-r--        04.01.2014     23:55            Documents
d-r--        04.01.2014     18:56            Downloads
d-r--        04.01.2014     15:19            Dropbox
d-r--        04.01.2014     14:30            Favorites
d----        15.10.2012     23:57            GNS3
d-r--        13.10.2013     23:48            Links
d-r--        13.10.2013     23:48            Music
d----        17.09.2012     18:22            pdf-Office
d-r--        04.01.2014     17:12            Pictures
d----        18.04.2012     22:38            Roaming
d-r--        13.10.2013     23:48            Saved Games
d-r--        13.10.2013     23:48            Searches
d----        12.12.2012     18:00            SparkleShare
d-r--        13.10.2013     23:48            Videos
d----        29.05.2013     09:26            vmws
-a---        15.10.2012     20:58        186 .packettracer
-a---        19.09.2012     14:53         81 CTX.DAT
-a---        07.03.2013     20:24        641 dateilink.lnk
-a---        02.01.2014     18:13      27369 history.cer
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is MinGW and MSYS. Take a look at this webpage: http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 1):

A basic UNIX environment that includes not only `bash`, `ls`, `pwd`, `cd`, but you can get pretty much everything up to and including `X` nicely packaged up and ready to go using `cygwin`, which [can be freely obtained](http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just write `powershell` in your good old `cmd` command prompt and it will turn into powershell.
Most of the commands work there.

You can switch back to command prompt by writing `cmd` again.